# Binding Image Control to URI in WP7

Tags: silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

I ham developing an application for WP7 and i am having a strange problem with Image control, it does not show the image it is binded to.

I have tryed it in so many ways but event this way (the most naive one) does not work:

In the xaml I have an Image control named img and this is what I have done in the code behind

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri   (@"http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/5365/photovnj.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

</code>
```

It seems to simple not to work...
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for me presuming you have `img` declared as an `Image` in your xaml.

If not, I'd suggest you have a connection problem from your app running in the emulator or device to the internet.

This is the code I wrote.

```
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/5365/photovnj.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: i am working on a computer that is behind a proxy... but I thought since it works in IE and FF it will be fine here ( i am not getting any sort of exeptions... strange... I will have to try it at home.  Thanks!!!

Comment: no worries, you might look at this on proxy support if you havent already too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754351(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: it works at home! what i am doing is getting some posts of a blog's feed using httpwebrequest. the posts come back fine but the images does not... weird!

Comment: That is strange yea, you could compare observations from site to site using Fiddler to find out more of what's going on.